# Convert lisp function to use map

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Hello I am looking forward to convert my existing function:

```
(defun checkMember (L A)
  (cond
    ((NULL L) nil)
    ( (and (atom (car L)) (equal (car L) A))  T )
    (T  (checkMember (cdr L) A))))
```

To use map functions, but i honestly cant understand exactly how map functions work, could you maybe advice  me how this func's work?

this is my atempt:

```
(defun checkMem (L A)
  (cond
    ((NULL L) nil)
    ( (and (atom (car L)) (equal (car L)  (car A)))  T )
    (T  (mapcar #'checkMem  (cdr L) A))))
```

Comment: Consider also `some`. Although it doesn't have "map" in its name it is another sequence processing function: `(some (lambda (e) (equal A e)) L)`

Comment: @m-n, that's the most correct answer: this is not about mapping and `some` returns as soon as something is true.  If you post an answer, I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
(defun checkMember (L a)
  (car (mapcan #'(lambda (e)
                   (and (equal a e) (list T)))
               L)))
```

Note: it does not recurse into list elements, but the original function did not either.

Comment: so with map functions using lambdas would be the way of doing stuff ?:D

Comment: No, not at all. Using `map` or relative to do that kind of search is strange. But it's possible.

Comment: And  another question , is it  possible to extened the same lambda to work on in a reccurent way? (to be able to identify the element  on any level) ?

Comment: Yes it is. Implementation is left as an exercise.

Comment: What do you think? :D 
`(defun checkMemberL (L a)
  (car (mapcan
          #'(lambda (e)
            (cond
              ((atom e)
              (and (equal a e) '(T)))
              ((listp e) checkMemberL(e, a))
            )
       L)))`

Comment: @BogdanM. Recursive version updated that you are asking about.

Comment: Almost: `(defun checkMember (L a)
  (car (mapcan #'(lambda (e)
                   (cond
                    ((atom e) (and (equal a e) '(T)))
                    ((listp e) (and  (checkMember e a) '(T))) )) L)))`

Comment: Yet it is so ugly, I really think using `map` is evil in this case.

Comment: OOPS! `mapcan` is destructive (it works as if by `nconc`). But you returned a constant list `'(T)`.  Under `mapcan`, you must always return freshly allocated lists.  It would be more n00b friendly if Common Lisp had `mappend` built-in.

Comment: Indeed. My Common Lisp is rather rusty. `(list t)` should be used instead of `(t)`.

Comment: Its ok guys I am learning  for a examen and  we are working with clisp, I'm not lookign forward to  ace this paradigms but my teacher is bad,,,, that beeing sad i learn everything on my own, and  well you the So community :) thanks. The map part was required  because that was the way teacher asked.

Answer (score 7):

A mapping function is not appropriate here because the task involves searching the list to determine whether it contains a matching item. This is not mapping.

Mapping means passing each element through some function (and usually collecting the return values in some way). Sure, we can abuse mapping into solving the problem somehow.

But may I instead suggest that this is a *reduce* problem rather than a *mapping* problem? Reducing means processing all the elements of a list in order to produce a single value which summarizes that list.

Warm up: use `reduce` to add elements together:

```
(reduce #'+ '(1 2 3)) -> 6
```

In our case, we want to reduce the list differently: to a single value which is `T` or `NIL` based on whether the list contains some item.

Solution:

```
(defun is-member (list item)
  (reduce (lambda (found next-one) (or found (eql next-one item)))
          list :initial-value nil))

;; tests:
(is-member nil nil) -> NIL
(is-member nil 42) -> NIL
(is-member '(1) 1) -> T
(is-member '(1) 2) -> NIL
(is-member '(t t) 1) -> NIL  ;; check for accumulator/item mixup
(is-member '(1 2) 2) -> T
(is-member '(1 2) 3) -> NIL
...
```

A common pattern in using a (left-associative) reduce function is to treat the left argument in each reduction as an accumulated value that is being "threaded" through the reduce. When we do a simple reduce with `+` to add numbers, we don't think about this, but the left argument of the function used for the reduction is always the partial sum. The partial sum is initialized to zero because `reduce` first calls the `+` function with no arguments, which is possible: `(+)` is zero in Lisp.

Concretely, what happens in `(reduce #'+ '(1 2 3))` is this:

- first, `reduce` calls `(+)` which returns `0`.
- then, reduce calls `(+ 0 1)`, which produces the partial sum `1`.
- next, reduce calls `(+ 1 2)`, using the previous partial sum as the left argument, and the next element as the right argument. This returns `3`, of course.
- finally, reduce calls `(+ 3 3)`, resulting in `6`.

In our case, the accumulated value we are "threading" through the reduction is not a partial sum, but a boolean value. This boolean becomes the left argument which is called `found` inside the reducing function.  We explicitly specify the initial value using `:initial-value nil`, because our lambda function does not support being called with no arguments.  On each call to our lambda, we short-circuit: if `found` is true, it means that a previous reduction has already decided that the list contains the item, and we just return true. Otherwise, we check the right argument: the next item from the list. If it is equal to `item`, then we return `T`, otherwise `NIL`.  And this `T` or `NIL` then becomes the `found` value in the next call. Once we return `T`, this value will "domino" through the rest of the reduction, resulting in a `T` return out of `reduce`.

If you insist on using mapping, you can do something like: map each element to a list which is empty if the element doesn't match the item, otherwise nonempty. Do the mapping in such a way that the lists are catenated together. If the resulting list is nonempty, then the original list must have contained one or more matches for the item:

```
(defun is-member (list item)
  (if (mapcan (lambda (elem)
                (if (eq elem item) (list elem))) list)
     t))
```

This approach performs lots of wasteful allocations if the list contains many occurrences of the item.

(The `reduce` approach is also wasteful because it keeps processing the list after it is obvious that the return value will be `T`.)

Comment: And in the specific case of "find something", this could, in theory, use the special-case reducer `ANY`.

Comment: Excelent answere, if only my potato teacher would be able to explain like this... (sadly the exam is by, waiting for the result  now) Thanks a lot for all the quality information

Comment: This is well explained, but it's not entirely accurate, as the function is not called with zero arguments in this case.  "If the subsequence is empty and no initial-value is given, then the function is called with zero arguments, and reduce returns whatever function does. This is the only case where the function is called with other than two arguments." ([CLHS REDUCE](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_reduce.html)).  For instance, try: `(reduce (lambda (&rest args) (print (length args))) '(1 2 3))`

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun memb (item list)
  (map nil
       (lambda (element)
         (when (eql item element)
           (return-from memb t)))
       list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**Recursive version:**

```
(defun checkmember (l a)
 (let ((temp nil))
  (cond ((null l) nil) ((find a l) (setf temp (or temp t)))
   (t
    (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cond ((listp x)(setf temp (or temp (checkmember x a))))))
     l)))
  temp))
```

Usage: `(checkmember '(1 (2 5) 3) 20)` => NIL

`(checkmember '(1 (2 5) 3) 2)` => T

`(checkmember '(1 2 3) 2)` => T

`(checkmember '((((((((1)))))))) 1)` = T

Comment: It does not work. `checkmember` is a function that takes two arguments, but `mapcar` expects a function that takes one argument. Also, `(checkMember '(1 2 3) 2)` does not return `T`.

Comment: Not workign as expecting since
`[31]> (memberLambda '(1 2 3) 3)
(NIL NIL T)` but I will still work  try to find a way

Comment: @FrédéricDumont Hope it works now for all scenarios.

Comment: No, it does not. Try `(isthere '(((1))) 1)`.

Comment: @FrédéricDumont Fixed, thanks for bringing it to my attention, I took simple list check for granted.

Comment: Not yet: `(checkmember '((1 2) (3 4)) 2)` returns `nil`. The problem is that you set `temp` to whatever the last check did (true or false), when you want to set it to true if possible, and never back to false.

Comment: @FrédéricDumont you were right, I think now it is done !